# How to remove defer nomodule from the index.html on angular build

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Im working on enterprise application with custom client requirement there i'm using spring boot mvc with theamleaf template resolver with the angular front end application ,
My question is about angular 8, that angular when i build angular application that generate index.html file with the defer attribute in every script tags those are not supported to the theamleaf template resolver to parse as html 5 .. those are worked on other angular version upto 7 but its not working on angular 8

my current build script is like this

```
<script src="runtime.js" defer></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule defer></script>
<script src="polyfills.js" defer></script>
<script src="styles.js" defer></script>
<script src="vendor.js" defer>
</script><script src="main.js" defer></script>
```

my expected result is like

```
  <script src="runtime.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script src="polyfills-es5.js" nomodule="nomodule" defer="defer">
```

if  i change the builded index file as my expected result by hand that work with my application but its not possible to use with git pipe line build profile , Please help -- Thanks